# why my photo can't be displayed in web?

Tags: firefox

There is a photo in c:/workspace/abbr.jpg.

```
<html>   
<body>  
<img src="file:\\c:/workspace/abbr.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">   
</body>  
</html>
```

Why it can not be displayed in the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three slashes:

```
<img src="file:///C:/workspace/abbr.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your 3. line to:

```
<img src="file:///C:/workspace/abbr.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<img src="file:///C:/workspace/abbr.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
```